# How to get the <h1> elements and then next sibling <h2> and <p> elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm working in python on a Selenium problem. I'm trying to gather each element with an h1 tag and following that tag, I want to get the closest h2 and paragraph text tags and place that data into an object.

My current code looks like:

```
cards = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h1")
ratings = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')

print(len(cards))
print(len(ratings))
print(len(descriptions))
```

which is generating inconsistent numbers.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, your question is not clear. Can you please show the source or page in question and explain in more detail what you want to extract, e.g. `//h1/h2[1] | //h1/p`

Comment: Please upload the html for same.

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `<h1>` tag elements and then the next sibling `<h2>` and `<p>` tag elements you can use the following solution:

```
cards = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h1")
ratings = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h1//following-sibling::h2")
descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h1//following-sibling::p")
print(len(cards))
print(len(ratings))
print(len(descriptions))
```